# API request times out ONLY if I pass parameters

Tags: ios, swift, get, digital-ocean, flask-restful

I am trying to figure out why any time I pass valid json to my server for a GET request the connection times out. I do not have any problems passing json to my server in any other request type other than GET... I've tested the server-side code locally and the queries work as expected.

I want to fetch a specific user from my database and I need to pass in a username, so I send the username to the server.

The error I keep getting (If I don't send any paramaters to the server, and just return current_user, it works and I don't get this error)

```
 Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x604000454c40 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001
```

Here is the part of the API call code where I set the request type and values to send to the server, in case:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = jsonData
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
```

Server set up, just in case it matters: 

Digitalocean droplet, Linux, Ubuntu 16.04, Nginx

**EDIT/ UPDATE**
If I change the method from a GET to a POST (and keep the server code exactly the same), the server sends the correct data back immediately.

The server side code for this is very short, so I really don't see how it can be timing out due to optimization:

```
user = UserModel.find_by_username(data['username'])

    if user:
        return {"response": [user.json()]}, 200
    return {"response": "user not found"}, 404
```

It really seems as if we can't send json via a GET method. It doesn't seem to work on both a simulator nor an actual device...I saw a similar SO post where someone commented exactly what I'm experiencing. Changing GET to POST was the fix....but it is a GET request, so why wouldn't this work?

Comment: A timeout means that the 'server side was unable to serve the response in a timely fashion' meaning that the server side code for fetching the results is likely not optimised. it should be nothing to do with your client app. so your question should probably be around the server implementation

Comment: You could try increasing the time out interval in `NSURLSessionConfiguration` and use that configuration for your session

Comment: @Scriptable the server side code is literally one line of sqlalchemy code and when i change the method type from GET to POST, it returns the data immediately to iphone simulator...

Comment: @user1046037 I appreciate the suggestion but I really don't think that is the reasoning... please see my update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GET-Method does not support http body. When you send your parameter as url encoded it will work.

Example:

```
http://www.example.de?username=abc
```